# adding a uibutton over uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to add a UIButton in a fixed position on my view, over my `UITableView`. I'm using a `UITableViewController` and Storyboard.

In the image below, the black square with the white triangle is static; i.e. it always remains in that position no matter where you scroll to with the UITableView. How can I replicate this?

[image]

Comment: `[[self.tableView superView] addSubview:view]`?

Comment: create a normal UIViewController, add the tableview then add the button over the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a UIViewController and add your UITableview onto that controller's view, then you can add your button as a subview of that controller's view above the UITableview.

Comment: I see. How would I hook up the datasource/delegate of the UITableView?

Comment: in your UIViewController's .h, make it look like `@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` then you can set it as the UITableView's delegate/datasource.